# Why are we allowed to use a parameter defined by an "is" expression in the else clause of a conditional operator?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, .net-core, conditional-operator

Example:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;

int result = (a + b) is int sum && sum < 100 ? sum : sum - 1;
```

The expression `sum - 1` is valid, and sum is still in scope, even though it's in the else condition. Why is that so? I take it that if the `is` expression returns false, sum would bear its default value, which for `int` is `0`?

Comment: Change the first line of code to `long a = int.MaxValue;` and see what happens.

Comment: @mjwills yeah, the compiler throws a compile-time error. If we had generics though or boxing, I think it wouldn't be the same case.

Comment: It either knows at compile time that is in an `int`, or it doesn't. I suspect the other scenarios will act consistently (as shown by @canton7 below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the compiler can prove that `a + b` is always an `int`, and so it knows that the `is int` test will always be run, and will always pass. Therefore it knows that `sum` is always assigned, regardless of what happens during the rest of the condition.

Try using something that might not be an `int`, and see that you get an error:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
object sumObject = a + b;

// error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'sum'
int result = sumObject is int sum && sum < 100 ? sum : sum - 1;
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this, which also means that `sum` might not always be assigned:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;

// error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'sum'
int result = false && (a + b) is int sum && sum < 100 ? sum : sum - 1;
```

Comment: The var-pattern would seem more appropriate, since the type needs not be tested here: `(a + b) is var sum`. The [is (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) says: *var pattern, a match that always succeeds and binds the value of an expression to a new local variable.*.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `(a + b) is var sum && ...` is better than `int sum = a + b; ...`, but I know some people prefer it...

Comment: Here the question `var` or `int` is not about implicit versus explicit typing. `is int` is a type test while `is var` is solely used to create a temporary variable.

Comment: I know, yes. I'm commenting more on the practice of using `is var` solely to declare new variables in the middle of another expression